# Al enviar Correos con PHPMailer los correos recibidos tienen caracteres aleatorios en el sender

Tags: php, phpmailer

El problema es que estoy armando una webpage y he empezado a utilizar PHPMailer, pero si bien funciona correctamente, en el sender del email muestra caracteres aleatorios en vez de por ejemplo mi cuenta de correo de mi web page (alojada en Hostinger), como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: random letters and numbers in mail sender]

Esto es lo que tengo en el archivo php que maneja el formulario:

```
 require_once('./vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
    
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    
 $mail = new PHPMailer();

 $body = '<h4>' . 'De: ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido . '</br>' . 'email: ' . $email . ', teléfono: '. ($telefono != '' ? $telefono : 'No especificado') . '</h4>' . $mensaje;
             $mail->setFrom($email . ' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido);
             $mail->addReplyTo($email . ' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido);
             $mail->addAddress('arabitaliano@hotmail.com', 'DGF Desarrollo Web');
             $mail->Subject = 'Alguien ha enviado un mensaje en www.dgf-desarrolloweb.com';
             $mail->CharSet = "UTF8";
             $mail->msgHTML($body);
             $mail->send();
```

Espero que sea suficiente información y que haya forma de arreglarlo para que no aparezcan esos caracteres aleatorios sino un from con el email del remitente (introducido en campo requerido en el formulario del website). Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que me puedan proveer.

Comment: responde mi respuesta tu pregunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los recipientes deben ser declarados por ejemplo:

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
```

Si observas el metodo `setFrom` envia dos valores: Correo y Nombre de usuario, el nombre de usuario puede ser opcional. en tu ejemplo no lo estas implementando correctamente. estas haciendo una concatenacion de texto en su lugar lo cual puede prestarce para errores...

Tambien es importante que veas si tu libreria esta actualizada, en la ultima versiones el metodo `msgHTML` ha dado problema y se debe sustituir por la combinacion `IsHTML` + `Body`
Documentacion: [Link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example)

tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

```php
require_once('./vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
    
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $body = '<h4>' . 'De: ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido . '</br>' . 'email: ' . $email . ', teléfono: '. ($telefono != '' ? $telefono : 'No especificado') . '</h4>' . $mensaje;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF8";
    $mail->setFrom($email , $nombre . ' ' . $apellido);
    $mail->addReplyTo($email , $nombre . ' ' . $apellido);
    $mail->addAddress('arabitaliano@hotmail.com', 'DGF Desarrollo Web');
    $mail->Subject = 'Alguien ha enviado un mensaje en www.dgf-desarrolloweb.com';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! En un rato veo si se arregla lo del remitente en caracteres aleatorios (que supongo representan mi web hosting o su email "de salida").

Comment: He agregado el código provisto y ahora el intentar responder al email enviado por mi página aparece correctamente con el email que proveyó el usuario al llenar el formulario pero mi el remitente del email recibido sigue apareciendo como en la imagen del post original :/ Me gustaría que apareciera o bien la cuenta de correo de mi web hosting o el email provisto por el usuario. Además siempre me manda el correo a la carpeta spam >.<

Comment: @JamelSeyek eso esta raro...  no debería de ser...  es posible que el correo se esté enviado a través del sistema de correo de tu host...  estas usando SMTP??  mira como se implementa según el ejemplo y verifica las diferencia puede ser que no estés haciendo correctamente la implementacion de la libreria

Comment: No estaba usando SMTP. Tampoc se bien cómo usarlo pero buscando info encontré algo y le añadí el siguiente código:

$mail->isSMTP();
         $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
         $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
         $mail->Port = 587;
         $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
         $mail->Username = 'aqui le puse mi usuario';
         $mail->Password = 'aquí le puse mi contraseña';
         $mail->setFrom('contacto@dgf-desarrolloweb.com', 'DGF Desarrollo Web');
         $mail->addReplyTo('contacto@dgf-desarrolloweb.com', 'DGF Desarrollo Web');

Y ahora la página contacto no carga

Comment: Bueno, lo pude solucionar gracias a tu ayuda. El problema era que como dijiste y evidentemente no leí lo suficientemente bien, setFrom tenía un solo parámetro que era una cadena de texto concatenada. Al añadir una coma pude hacer que el remitente apareciera bien. Gracias!